# Drawing a graph with given vertices edges and face on genus 1

Tags: graph-theory, surfaces, topological-graph-theory

I want to draw a graph on the genus 1 surface. The graph has 
2 vertex, 6 edges and 4 faces hence it by Euler Characteristics formula it lives on genus 1 surface. 
I want to add an extra condition that I want 3 faces of degree 2 and 1 face of degree 6. Apriori I don't know if such a graph would exist? It also satisfies handshaking lemma.

I could imagine a graph in a sphere and draw it having 
2 vertex, 6 edges and 6 faces. Any vizulaztion help or a picture would really help me in this case.

Comment: You could easily reduce the face count by one with a "wormhole" joining the interiors of two faces. Try with a wormhole with each end hitting an edge, and join the ends in a twisted manner through the wormhole ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s a start. Draw the torus as a square with sides identified, and draw the following graph:

[image: torus graph]

This graph has two vertices (red and blue), four edges, and two faces (green and yellow). Can you modify this graph to add two extra edges and two extra faces?

---

With the change in requirements, here is another approach:

[image: torus graph 2]

This had two vertices, six edges, and four faces. Three faces have degree 2, and one has degree 6.

Comment: If I add two edges joining red to blue isn't that give me a two more face? Then all the faces is of degree 2? What I want is one face of degree 6 and all other faces of degree 2.

Comment: If you add two more edges, you do indeed get two more faces — for a total of two vertices, six edges, and four faces. I see two faces of degree two, and two of degree four. If you want additional requirements on your graph, you should edit your question or ask a new one.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit the question.

Comment: @GGT I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would think of the graph I ask in my question is embedded in a kettle like an object that is an object of genus 1. More formally its a ball and a strip glued together. We fix two points at the junction where the strip is glued to the ball. [image]

So there are three faces of degree 2 and one face of degree 6 and complement of the graph produces a disjoint union of the disk.